# working of an sr latch

Tags: digital-logic

I am confused with the working of an sr latch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkRbMI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The two inputs provided to nand1 is S and q2 and the inputs provided to nand2 is r and q1. q1 is the output of nand1 and q2 is the output of nand 2. When s=0 and r=1, according to what my book says, nand1 will have 0 and 'x' as an input(where x can be any bit 0 or 1 as it doesn't matter because anything NANDed with 0 results in a 1). So the result q1 is 1 which is fed to nand2 along with r=1 to give q2=0. Now here is where I am getting confused- Initially if we assume that we have just constructed this latch. Then obviously both q1 and q2 will be zero since nothing has been commenced. Since both the bits s and r come at the same time, so when s goes to nand1 then at the same precise time r goes to nand2. Now if we take the above values again, i.e(s=0,r=1), nand1 is provided with s=0 and q2=0 which results in q1=1. And nand2 at the same time is provided with r=1 and q1=0 that results in q2=1. This results in the unwanted stage where both outputs are 1.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Also, it's unusual in English to say you "have a doubt." You might say you are "confused about the following" or "have questions about..." *Doubt* means you do not trust information that was provided to you. As in, "This diode is supposed to handle 3 amps, but I doubt that."

Comment: I still don't see a question anywhere. Also, please label the signal names on the schematic. Your assumption that both outputs will be initially zero because "nothing has commenced" is wrong and the language is not appropriate. Try to clarify a specific question.

Comment: It's not a question. I just wanted someone to clarify the confusion I had.

Answer (score 1):

When a SR latch is constructed as you said there will be a case where both outputs are at logic high. But when input s = "0" and r = "1" is given as output q1 will become "1" and and q2 will become "0". This is more stable state for a SR latch.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit is not stable in the state you describe.  When Q1 goes high, both inputs of NAND2 are high, and its output goes low.

Comment: Yeah that's correct. But I want you to imagine how the electronic pulses travel. For that I want to ask you a set of questions.                                                        -When the circuit is built, initially ,since no electronic signals is provided to the latch aren't both outputs q1 and q2 equal to zero?                                              Keeping this in mind whatever value we feed into the latch the output q1 and q2 will be equal to 1, right?

Comment: As, initially, since q1=0 and q2=0 and let the values of s and r be anything. When s is inputted to nand1 it is has q2=0 also as the input. This produces q1=1. But I am not considering this output as an input to the nand2 because in this there would be a propogation delay by which the signal of r would be lost. I am taking q1=0 and r=x for nand2 assuming that it is being operated at the same exact time as nand1 is being operated. If i take this then the output q2 would be 1. But that's unwanted. Here's where I need some clarification.

Comment: You say that Q1 = 1. But then you say you are not considering this to be an input to NAND2. Why not? It clearly _is_ an input. Are you asking how does the circuit behave as power is being applied? It is meaningless; outputs are not to be considered valid until the power supply has stabilized. The latch will settle into an unambiguous state once the power is up. Or, are you concerned that both Q1 and Q2 may both have the same level for a few nanoseconds before the input has fully propagated through both NAND gates? Well, that's just the way asynchronous logic works.